# PHP variable scope within Try/Catch block

Tags: php, exception, scope, try-catch

In PHP, how do variable scope rules apply to Try/Catch blocks? Do variables declared within the `try` block go out of scope when the block has finished? Or are they in scope until the end of the function/method?

For example:

```
try
{
   // This may throw an exception when created!
   $o = new Pronk();
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
   // Handle & exit somehow; not important here
   return false;
}

$o->doPronk();
```

Is this valid? Or should `$o = NULL;` be set before the try/catch to keep `$o` in scope?

(I know that the sample code *does* work, however I also know PHP can get a little stupid when it comes to scoping. My question is, ideally, how *should* it work? What is the correct and proper way to do this?)

Comment: PHP doesn't have block scope. Variable scope is the whole function.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your code is valid. Variable scope in PHP is by function, not block. So you can assign a variable inside the `try` block, and access it outside, so long as they're in the same function.

Comment: Super simple answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is opinion based mostly. The code is correct and it will work as expected as long as the `catch` block always has the `return` statement. if the `catch` block does not return, the flow will continue and the code outside the try/catch block will be executed, and it will fail, because `$o` won't be initialized. You will be able to access `$o` because of the lack of block scope in php, but the method won't exist because the object construction failed.

Answer (score 1):

the main concept for the exception handling is that if anything goes wrong inside the "try" block the code will enter into the "catch" block. so if

```
$o = new Pronk();
```

does not raise any error it will be in scope. we don't have to declare it before try/catch block.
your code is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your obj is correctly constructed
you can expect to use `obj` outside of try/catch block

However, suppose that there was an exception during construction.
Then your `obj` wouldn't be even constructed inside try block.
Therefore, you wouldn't be able to call the functions on `obj` because `obj` was not even created.