# Laravel Postman crud use id in url

Tags: laravel, api, postman

So i made a **crud API** in laravel for clients and want to test it in postman, but i have a problem/question.
i try to find the id of the clients in the api but it can't find it, and i dont know why.
I want to give the id in the postman url.

in the api routes i have the $id like this:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], "/clients/{id?}", "ApiV2Controller@clients");
```

and in the `clients` function:

```
public function clients(Request $request, $id = null){

if($id){
        $client = Client::find($id);
        if(is_null($client)){
            return $this->sendError("404", 'client not found');
        }
    }
    else{
        $client = new Client;  
    }

    $client->clt_name = $request->name; 
    $client->clt_adress = $request->adress;
    $client->save();
}
```

And the Postman URL:

```
localhost:8000/api/v2/clients/19?name=TestName&adress=TestAdress
```

And it says `client not found`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you paste here  the whole clients function and is there any client of id 19 in your database ?

Comment: edited the post, and no there is no client where id = 19

Comment: if there is no client where id = 19, then the output is correct. what's the problem then?

Comment: it should make a new record, but it doesnt. not sure if i made the right postman url.

Comment: nah you are not thinking about the case where id is not null and that id is not stored in your database.

Comment: not sure what i'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code. i think you want to create the client if there is no valid client_id in your database. Here is the solution:

```
public function clients(Request $request, $id = null)
{
    try{
        $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        $client = new Client;
    }
    $client->clt_name = $request->name; 
    $client->clt_adress = $request->adress;
    $client->save();
}
```

Comment: The scope is wrong, `$client` only exists in your try-catch block, not after.

Comment: Variable scope in PHP is by function, not block. So you can assign a variable inside the try block, and access it outside, so long as they're in the same function.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488313/php-variable-scope-within-try-catch-block